# How I can keep only the non repeated lines in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, uniq

Want I want to do is simply keep the lines which are not repeated in a huge file like this:

```
..
a
b
b
c
d
d
..
```

The desired output is then:

```
..
a
c
..
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `d` being repeated in last 2 lines?

Comment: is your file sorted? do you want to preserve the order of the lines in your file?

Comment: @anubhava Yeah sorry, edit. the `..` simbol represent infinite rows.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I want to keep the order so no sort can't be used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`uniq` has arg `-u`

```
  -u, --unique          only print unique lines
```

Example:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\nb\nc\nd\nd\n' | uniq -u
a
c
```

If your data is not sorted, do `sort` at first

```
$ printf 'd\na\nb\nb\nc\nd\n' | sort | uniq -u
```

---

### Preserve the order:

```
$ cat foo
d
c
b
b
a
d

$ grep -f <(sort foo | uniq -u) foo
c
a
```

`greps` the file for patterns obtained by aforementioned `uniq`. I can imagine, though, that if your file is really huge then it will take a long time.

The same without somewhat ugly *Process substitution*:

```
$ sort foo | uniq -u | grep -f- foo
c
a
```

Comment: Note printf can take multiple args: `printf '%s\n' a b c d`

Comment: @pacholik The second edited option is better. Thank very much.

Answer (score 2):

This awk should work to list only lines that are not repeated in file:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++{dup[$0]} END {for (i in seen) if (!(i in dup)) print i}' file
a
c
```

Just remember that original order of lines may change due to hashing of arrays in awk.

**EDIT:** To preserve the original order:

```
awk '$0 in seen{dup[$0]; next}
     {seen[$0]++; a[++n]=$0}
     END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if (!(a[i] in dup)) print a[i]}' file

a
c
```

This is job that is tailor made for `awk` which doesn't require multiple processes, pipes and process substitution and will be more efficient for bigger files.

Comment: Sorry I want to keep the order of the rest of rows

Comment: ok I just got back from work, have updated the answer to take care of order as well. Hope you read my comment on using `awk` :)

Answer (score -2):

When your file is sorted, it's simple:

```
cat file.txt | uniq > file2.txt
mv file2.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, my fail. uniq -u would work well, as mentioned above.